# Can you put CSP headers or some other headers on your cdn

Tags: content-security-policy

I have 2 urls:

1. is for my main domain where I serve my content: `https://example.com`
2. is for my images cdn from where I serve images
   `https://images.example.com`

Are there any CSP headers I can add to my CDN domain that would prevent an attacker from including my images (`https://images.example.com`) via image tag or javascript  from his example domain `https://attacker.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSP is set on a document (typically with content type text/html) to declare what sources are allowed for that page. If you set this for your main domain you define what resources can and can't be loaded on pages on this domain.

On your CDN you could restrict what is being framed by X-Frame-Options or CSP frame-ancestors and you could restrict what is loaded as data by CORS headers. Preventing who loads your images would require some type of access control, but can't be achieved by response headers as there is no mechanism for this in the browser.